# How to handle list

Tags: list

I have a question: how to filter or map a function which filter out the lists I don't want?
Here is task:
recursion is not allowed, you  must use filter or map to loop through lists.
(define-struct fruit (name price))

;[list of list of structs][list of numbers]-->[list of structs]

(define myfruit fruits unwanted-price)...)

check expect: input:

```
  (myfruit

   (list (list (make-fruit 'apple 3) (make-fruit 'banane 4) (make-fruit 'avocado 5)) 

         (list (make-fruit 'apple 7)(make-fruit 'avocado 5))
  
          (list (make-fruit 'apple 7)(make-fruit 'avocado 9) (make-fruit 'banana 2)))
   (list 5 4))
```

output:

```
  (list (make-fruit 'apple 7)(make-fruit 'avocado 9) (make-fruit 'banana 2))
```

the  (list (make-fruit 'apple 3) (make-fruit 'banane 4) (make-fruit 'avocado 5)) is gone, because avocado'sprice is 5, banana's price is 4. (list (make-fruit 'apple 7)(make-fruit 'avocado 5)) is gone because avocado's price is 5.
I know to deal with list of structs, but have now idea how to deal with list of list of structs. the structure is so complicated.

please show me example how to handle it.

Comment: Step one: Come up with a function that returns true or false if a list of structures has one of the unwanted pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. We need a function to identify if a list of fruit has any fruit with an unwanted price
2. We need a function to identify if a list of fruit has any fruit with an unwanted price from a list of prices
3. We can filter out each sublist (in a list of list of fruit) using #2
4. Finally, we'll put all the "good" fruits in a list.

```
(define (has-unwanted-price lof p)
  (ormap (λ (f) (= (fruit-price f) p)) lof))

(define (has-unwanted-price-any lof lop)
  (ormap (λ (p) (has-unwanted-price lof p)) lop))

(define (myfruit fruits unwanted-prices)
  (flat (filter (λ (fruit-list) (not (has-unwanted-price-any fruit-list unwanted-prices))) fruits)))

(define (flat l)
  (apply append l))
```

Comment: thanks sincerely! btw, do you have any textbook to recommend? I have learnt half of the book: how to design programs. to deal with nexted lists (such as list of list of structs) I haven't seen similar examples in book and therefore get stucked easily. If there are books which can provides me examples to handle such complex lists, it would be very helpful. many textbooks I have found are only about basic use of Drracket/lisp

Comment: I would still recommend How to Design Programs. Maybe in your case the data design part was not as complete as it should've been. Consider the following initial data definitions: `; FruitBundle is a [List-of Fruit]` and `; FruitBasket is a [List-of FruitBundle]`. Now you can make templates, for each data definition and follow the self-referential design recipe. Later, you can use the abstraction design recipe to add the list-abstractions.